# installation of EJBCA as a CA

Tags: ejbca

root@casandbox:/home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2# ant runinstall
Buildfile: /home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/build.xml

customejbca.message:
[echo] No custom changes to merge.

appserver.error.message:

runinstall:

BUILD FAILED
/home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/build.xml:75: Basedir /home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/$EJBCA_HOME/bin does not exist

Total time: 0 seconds

##### but the dir exists; it's shown below

root@casandbox:/home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2# cd /home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/$EJBCA_HOME/bin
root@casandbox:/home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/bin#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look right with "$EJBCA_HOME" in the message. Are you using $EJBCA_HOME as a path somewhere (with the dollar sign)? The file it is looking for is simply "/home/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/bin/cli.xml". Did you set some configuration variable somewhere using the value "$EJBCA_HOME"?